# How to print a sorted column from matrix in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm new in C programming language, and I try to practice my skills in this language.

I'm coding an exercise about a matrix, where the user inputs the number of the column that wants to sort and print the column sorted (I'm using the bubble sort), but the program doesn't show me the answer.

This is my implementation of the problem.-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void bubble(int *array);
void print(int *array);

int main(){

    /*Este programa toma una columna y la ordena*/

    int fil=4, col=4;

    int matrix[fil][col];

    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){

        matrix[i][j]=rand()%10+1;   
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d\t",matrix[i][j]);            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int a, aux[col];

    printf("\nColumna a ordenar: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            if(j==a){
                aux[j]=matrix[0][j];
            }
            bubble(aux);
        }
    }

    getche();

}

void bubble(int *array){

    int length= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    int aux;

    for(int i=length-2;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                aux=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=aux;
                print(array);
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(int *array){

    int length= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
}
```

And, which book or tutorial should i follow to master the c language (C)?

Comment: `what book or tutorial recommend me to start in this language` -- this transforms the question into opinion-based.

Comment: First, decide whether you want C or C++. You will get different advice depending on the language. Second, maybe specify what the constraints are: For example, do you need to implement the sorting algorithm yourself? Are you allowed to call standard library functions other than `rand()` and `printf()`?

Comment: C Language, sorry; and I only wants to see the column sorted.

Comment: OK, I will remove the C++ tag. But then you cannot include `<iostream>` (which your code doesn't need anyway).

Comment: Ok. BTW, I'm new posting questions in StackOverFLow .-. What book or tutorial, about C, do you recommend me to learn the language?

Answer (score 2):

First : using

```
int length= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

cannot give you the number of elements of an array. Indeed, `sizeof(array)` will give you the size in memory of the pointer.
In C/C++, you must pass the number of elements of your arrays as an argument for the function using it. So your functions should be like :

```
void bubble(int *array, int size);
void print(int *array, int size);
```

Second : your loop

```
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        if(j==a){
            aux[j]=matrix[0][j];
        }
        bubble(aux);
    }
}
```

is unlikely to fill the `aux` array properly. Maybe something like :

```
int a, aux[fil];

printf("\nColumna a ordenar: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
    aux[i] = matrix[i][a];
}
bubble(aux, fil);
print(aux, fil);
```

rather than this double loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the third "for" loop in your main().

```
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        if(j==a){
            aux[j]=matrix[0][j];    //Should be aux[i]=matrix[i][j] here, or you're actually putting everything in aux[a], since j==a.
        }
        bubble(aux);
    }
}
```

Also, you should define aux as aux[fil]. Since fil==col, it's ok here. But aux is intended to be used to store a column instead of a row, so if your fil isn't eqaul to col, there would be problems.

You can write it like this:

```
int aux[fil];    
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
        aux[i]=matrix[i][a];
bubble(aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for which book, I can recommend nothing other than Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C Programming Language".